# OpenGL circle doesn't show up?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I am trying to draw a circle, but for some reason it doesn't show up.

Here is my code for the circle data:

```
#define M_PI 3.1415926535
#define NUMBER_OF_VERTICES 16

    const float radius = 0.5f;
    std::vector<float> buffer;

    for (double i = 0; i < 2 * M_PI; i += 2 * M_PI / NUMBER_OF_VERTICES)
    {
        buffer.push_back(cos(i) * radius);
        buffer.push_back(sin(i) * radius);
        buffer.push_back(0.0f);
    }

    unsigned int circleVBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &circleVBO);
    unsigned int circleVAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &circleVAO);

    glBindVertexArray(circleVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, circleVBO);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.size() * sizeof(float), buffer.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), buffer.data());
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

and here is my code when I draw the circle:

```
glBindVertexArray(circleVAO);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, NUMBER_OF_VERTICES);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

For reference, here is the entire cpp file:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <glfw/glfw3.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <vector>

#include "Shader.h"


const int windowWidth = 800;
const int windowHeight = 600;


void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);


void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void processInput(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}


int main()
{
    // Initialize
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);


    // Create window
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "Learning OpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);


    // Initialize glad
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }


    // Viewport
    glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);


    // Window resize callback
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);


    // Shader setup
    Shader shader("./Shaders/shader.vert", "./Shaders/shader.frag");


    // Circle data setup
#define M_PI 3.1415926535
#define NUMBER_OF_VERTICES 16
    const float radius = 0.5f;
    std::vector<float> buffer;
    for (double i = 0; i < 2 * M_PI; i += 2 * M_PI / NUMBER_OF_VERTICES)
    {
        buffer.push_back(cos(i) * radius);
        buffer.push_back(sin(i) * radius);
        buffer.push_back(0.0f);
    }
    unsigned int circleVBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &circleVBO);
    unsigned int circleVAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &circleVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(circleVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, circleVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.size() * sizeof(float), buffer.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), buffer.data());
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


    // Matrix transform
    glm::vec2 position = { 0.0f, 0.0f };
    float rotation = 0.0f;
    glm::vec2 scale = { 20.0f, 20.0f };
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(-800.0f, 800.0f, -600.0f, 600.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f }, glm::vec3{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }, glm::vec3{ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f });
    glm::mat4 trans = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    trans = glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(position.x, position.y, 0.0f));
    trans = glm::rotate(trans, glm::radians(rotation), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    trans = glm::scale(trans, glm::vec3(scale.x, scale.y, 1.0f));
    trans = projection * view * trans;
    shader.use();
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "transform"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(trans));


    // Main loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Input processing
        processInput(window);


        // Pre-draw
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        // Use shader
        shader.use();


        // Draw
        glBindVertexArray(circleVAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, NUMBER_OF_VERTICES);
        glBindVertexArray(0);


        // Post-draw
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }


    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

In terms of running the program, the window shows up with the expected background clear color, but nothing else.

Comment: and the only difference between the circle that doesn't work and the quad that does work is the data in the buffer?

Comment: The radius of the circle is 0.5. Because of your orthographic projection, this will result in a tiny dot on your screen. Increase the radius of the circle (e.g. 100.0f).

Comment: Why is your last argument to ``glVertexAttribPointer`` ``buffer.data()``? It should be the offset, which is 0.

Comment: user253751 - I do use an element array buffer for the quad just so that I don't have to repeat vertices, but that's about the only difference.

I tried each of these suggestions. It looks like as newQOpenGLWidget mentioned, I should have passed in (void*)0 for the offset instead of buffer.data(). That drew the circle on screen, then I tried what Rabbid76 said and increased the size of the radius and this now works as intended. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. The main problem is that the last argument for glVertexAttribPointer is supposed to be 0 or (void*)0.
2. The second issue is that the radius is too small for the orthographic projection. Increasing it from 0.5f should make the circle visible.

Comment: 1. Null pointers should always be written as `nullptr` (or `NULL` in C), not the number 0
2. When including somebody else's comment in your answer (Rabbid76 in this case), it is customary to at least credit them with the idea.